# Split string expression with multiple parenthesis (C#)

Tags: c#

I have below string and I want to split it in such a way that both the parameters of the function `fnGetDate` could be separated.

Function:

```
"fnGetDate('d',-1+ cint(cbool(DatePart('w',Date())<=2)) + cint(cbool(DatePart('w',Date())=2)))"
```

Desired output (after split):

```
[0] fnGetDate(

[1] 'd'

[2] -1+ cint(cbool(DatePart('w',Date())<=2)) + cint(cbool(DatePart('w',Date())=2))
```

Comment: So have you tried anything ?

Comment: have tried with Regular expression - ^(?>\((?<X>)|\)(?<-X>)|(?!\(|\)).)+(?(X)(?!)). Also tried to count the number of opening and closing parenthesis but not getting correct output

Comment: Add the code you have tried to the above question. Also add the output of the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, counting the number of opening and closing parenthesis is OK for you.

This example works for me:

```
string str = "fnGetDate('d',-1+ cint(cbool(DatePart('w',Date())<=2)) + cint(cbool(DatePart('w',Date())=2)))";
int parLevel = 0;
List<string> arguments = new List<string>();
string currentString = String.Empty;

foreach (char t in str)
{
    switch (t)
    {
        case '(':
            if (t == '(') parLevel++;
            currentString += t;
            if (parLevel == 1)
            {
                arguments.Add(currentString);
                currentString = String.Empty;
            }
            break;
        case ')':
            if (t == ')') parLevel--;
            if (parLevel > 0) currentString += t;
            break;
        case ',':
            if (parLevel == 1)
            {
                arguments.Add(currentString);
                currentString = String.Empty;
            } 
            else 
                currentString += t;
            break;
        default:
            currentString += t;
            break;
    }
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentString)) arguments.Add(currentString);

for (int i = 0; i < arguments.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("Argument {0}: {1}", i, arguments[i]);
```

[IDEOne Working Demo](http://ideone.com/0Ah9CY).

Comment: May need to add a bit of further checking in the case ',' section if there is the possibility that the first parameter is ','.

Comment: thanks for this, but I can't remove parenthesis from end result. Please check my desired output

Comment: @SystemOnline Such a strange desired output :) Look at my update. It gives absolutely the same result as you need.